# Javascript Anonymous Function Quiz

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

Given the following javascript code:

```
function countdown (num) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i += 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(num - i);
        }, i * 1000);
    }
}

countdown(5);
```

The desired result is a countdown from 5 to 0 using alert messages. Explain why the code only alerts -1, then fix the code so it works as expected.

I found the above javascript quiz and i really don't know how to solve it. I know it's anonymous functions and it has something to do with the variables scope but i consider it a great opportunity to learn if someone could explain me **why** it's not working and **what** needs to be done in order to work. I seek the theory behind the problem and the solution.

I know i can just read about Anonymous functions but an explanation using a ***"real problem"*** will help me visualize the problem and understand it better.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: http://blog.abhiomkar.in/2010/07/03/javascript-code-challenge-by-dropbox-team/

Comment: People are down voting the question but i already received 3 different ways to solve the problem. Thanks for your help people. I'll study all solutions you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the scope of `i` when the anonymous function is called the loop is over and `i`is in it's final value(-1). To solve this you can isolate a local scope with another anonymous function where you can redefine private variable `i` like this:

```
function countdown (num) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i += 1) {
        (function(i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert(num - i);
            }, i * 1000);
        })(i);
    }
}

countdown(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3p8FM/
You can resolve this way, binding the variables `num` and `i`

The alerts with -1 happened because the the scope of `i`. When the first function is really executed after the determined time, `i` has already the value of 6

Answer (score 0):

Change ur code as like this..
function countdown (num) {`enter code here`
   var j=0;setTimeout(function () { for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) { j=i; alert(num-i);}
        }, j*1000);
}

countdown(5);